# Why are there different types of bond configuration policies in linux, instead of one that can give a combined throughput and fail-over configuration?

Tags: networking, linux-networking, switch, bonding, mac-address

I am confused and not able to understand exactly the actual concept behind it. At switch level, what happens that prevents to use one globally accepted bond configuration policy?

And I don't understand why do we use specifically active-backup policy in our environment, instead of going for a better one that gives combined throughput, but not just fail-over configuration.

This website seems to have a good explanation: http://www.enterprisenetworkingplanet.com/linux_unix/article.php/3850636/Understanding-NIC-Bonding-with-Linux.htm

but I am unable to follow exactly. So, can someone explain it more clearer and try to explain in as much detail as possible what's happening at switch end and with the mac addresses?

Thanks.

Or you can also suggest a good book, where I can read everything about it and learn from scratch.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_aggregation has some information on the subject. It also has a good number of references for more information.

Comment: Because thats how Linux rolls, it is FOSS and has tons of flexibility.  Lots of people do unusual things with it.  Because different people have different needs.  Because some bonding methods work better for certain applications. Because some of the bonding modes are only compatible if you are connecting two Linux systems directly, and some only work when connecting to switches with bonding support.